# Evolution (3.48.4) (flatpak); cannot edit drafts

Tags: email, evolution

Evolution Flatpak 3.48.4
Ubuntu 22.04

I can save draft emails. I can view the draft email in the drafts folder.

But when I click on the draft email to edit the draft, 2 new windows are opened, and both windows are empty: no text appears for the draft. So no edits are possible.

Would anybody here have any ideas why this occurs?  Has Evolution a support group, and if so where can I find this group to help resolve such bugs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: enter the recipient.

I received unexpectedly this 'solution' from a Windows user...

The issue arises when the recipient field is left empty. When the recipient is entered, the draft will open properly with full text for editing. To open, click on the recipient field.

I was entirely unaware of this limitation prior, for the Evolution user guide has no mention whatsoever. This discussion is saved for the possible benefit to subsequent users.

-regards